# PHP Get Data inside an HTML Model element

Tags: php, bootstrap-5

i try to get data from data base with php to show in a model in html elements... i use foreach loop and get inside my data i get from database but it didnot change ID to view the data of it...it always show the last record
i try this with another way to open in another page and it work....but i wanna use it in same page ( [PHP_SELF] ) but i cant do it

```
<div class="main-slide">
    <div class="gallery">
                    
        <?php
        foreach($folders as $folder) {
                        
            echo '<div class="x-gallery text-center">';
            ?>
            <!-- Start option Span -->
            <span >
                <a href="#&foldid=<?php echo $folder['Folder_ID']?>">
                            
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" name="editFolder" data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                    data-bs-target="#exampleModalOption">
                <i class='fa-solid fa-pen-to-square'></i>
            </button>
        
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalOption" tabindex="-1" 
                aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Options </h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
                                    aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container">

                            <form class="form-horizontal main-form" 
                            action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ; ?>" 
                            method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <!-- ID Input Hidden -->
                                <input type="hidden" name="foldid" 
                                   value="<?php echo $folder['Folder_ID']?>"> 
                                <!--  User Name field -->
                                <div class="mb-3 row col-mid-4">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Folder Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input 
                                                type="text" 
                                                name="name" 
                                                class="form-control"
                                                value ="<?php echo $folder['Folder_Name'] ?>" 
                                                autocomplete="off"
                                                required="required"
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-8 md-flex justify-content-md-end">
                                        <input type="submit" name="editFolder" value="Save" 
                                            class="btn btn-primary " />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</span>
<!-- End Option Span -->

    <?php
    echo "<span class=''>".$folder['Folder_Name']."</span>";
    if(empty($folder['Folder_Cover'])) {
        
        echo "<a href='#'>
        <img class='card-img-top' src='images/no-image.jpg' alt='empty'>
        </a> ";
    }else {
        
        echo "<a href='#'>
                <img class='card-img-top' 
                    src='data/uploads/album-Images/".$folder['Folder_Cover']."' alt=''>
            </a> ";
    }
                        
                        echo"</div>";
                    }
                    
                    ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: if you add an index to the forloop, foreach($folders as $key=>$folder) you can use this index to keep the ID field unique by adding data-bs-target="#exampleModalOption_<?php echo $key;?>" then same for the modal id id="exampleModalOption_<?php echo $key;?>"

Comment: Awesome! glad you got it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Marty's suggestion in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730721/php-get-data-inside-an-html-model-element/75730810#comment133596099_75730721), I was able to resolve the problem:

> `foreach($folders as $key=>$folder)` you can use this index to keep the ID field unique by adding `data-bs-target="#exampleModalOption_<?php echo $key;?>"` then same for the modal id `id="exampleModalOption_<?php echo $key;?>"`